# How can I access the source code of my mouse via the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse

I'm currently using a *Roccat Kone Pure* mouse on my Mac. Unfortunately, the file that should be installed to control the lighting of that mouse is only accessible for Windows or Linux users.

Without that file, the lighting "pulses" on a constant level which is really annoying and I'd like to stop it. As a file can have access to the control system of that mouse, it should also be possible to access it via the terminal. But how?

Comment: If you can find the Linux command to change the lights, please edit that in the post. All I can tell is there’s custom software so you’d need to take the mouse to a pc or Linux and run that software or virtualize one of those OS on top of Mac. Maybe I’m missing an easy fix, though.

Comment: Just doing some cursory research, the Linux drivers *aren't* provided by ROCCAT.  Technically, the product is a Windows Product but there's Linux support from community development.  You may want to check out the [development site](http://roccat.sourceforge.net/general.html) or even contact [the developer](https://sourceforge.net/u/userid-1715267/profile/) (obtained from ROCCAT's site support site)